# Is there an action principle for the dynamics of a relativistic fluid?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism

I wish to know if there is any way to get the convective derivative of the 4-velocity
$$
u^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}u^{\nu}
$$

from a lagrangian density $L(u^\mu,\partial_{\nu}u^{\mu})$ in order to describe the equation of motion for a relativistic fluid. This equation, for the forceless case is
$$
u^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}u^{\nu} = 0.
$$

The Euler-Lagrange equation would be
$$
\partial_{\nu}\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \partial_{\nu}u^{\mu}} = \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial u^{\mu}}
$$

So, how could I get the second equation from the third one?

Furthermore, I wanted to know if it would be possible to include an electromagnetic interaction term
$$
j_{(mass)}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}u^{\nu} = F^{\nu}_{\mu}j_{(charge)}^{\mu}
$$

but that's a bit secondary